# How to replace click function with span id

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a jquery dropdown menu. (demo [here](http://www.filamentgroup.com/examples/menus/flyout.php))

And what I needed to do is to get the full path of what the users choose and to validate that there's no more options to the right.
The original idea (before dropdown menu, with just regular li/ul) was accomplished with this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q6yDe/588/)

As you can see, there's validation and a full path variable for later usage.

Now, what I'd like to achieve is the same thing with the drop down menu.

This is the code in which I fill a Label with the Users' choice based on the Dropdown Menu.

```
<asp:Label ID="LabelMenu" text="" runat="server" /> <span id="menuSelection"></span>
```

As you can see, the span id `menuSelection` is the one getting the result.

So my question is. How can I replace the `click` function shown on the fiddle, for the `menuSelection` result?

The goal is to get full path and validation once the user has chosen a field from the Dropdown Menu

Regards.

Comment: The JS Fiddle you link to uses jQuery 1.4.2; is that version required?  Also, in both the Fiddle and your linked page you use `ul`/`li` to represent the menu structure. If that's the case then `change()` won't work (since it's tied to only `input`, `textarea` and `select` elements).

Comment: @DavidThomas thanks for the input. ul/li is needed since it's the source for the menues. So change() is not an option.

Comment: use live or on or delegate instead click. it's not working in dropDown case because you don't have that elements available in your DOM. So if you use live or on or delegate, in that case it'll work whenever your element'll add in your DOM

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **change** event instead of **click**

```
$("select").on('change' , function() {
```

Comment: not familiar with the usage, would it be something like $("#mylist a").on('change', //rest of code ?

Comment: Change can be used for select or input elements

Answer (score 1):

I might misunderstood you but this would at least give you an idea.

resources:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

html:

```
<label id="LabelMenu" text="" runat="server" />
<span id="menuSelection">My Span List</span>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Flag to prevent multiple insertion
    var flag = false;
    $("#menuSelection").click(function() {
        // Prevent inserting more than 1 menu
        if (flag == false) {
            // Your menu
            $('<ul id="mylist"> <li><a href="#">First Level 1</a> <ul> <li><a href="#">FL1 Second Level 1</a></li> <li><a href="#">FL1 Second Level 2</a></li> </ul> </li> <li><a href="#">First Level 2</a> <ul> <li><a href="#">FL2 Second Level 1</a> <ul> <li><a href="#">FL2 SL1 Third Level 1</a></li> </ul> </li> <li><a href="#">FL2 Second Level 2</a> <ul> <li><a href="#">FL2 SL2 Third Level 1</a></li> </ul> </li> <li><a href="#">FL2 Second Level 3</a></li> </ul> </li> <li><a href="#">First Level 3</a> <ul> <li><a href="#">FL3 Second Level 1</a> <ul> <li><a href="#">FL3 SL1 Third Level 1</a></li> <li><a href="#">FL3 SL1 Third Level 2</a></li> </ul> </li> <li><a href="#">FL3 Second Level 2</a></li> <li><a href="#">FL3 Second Level 3</a> <ul> <li><a href="#">FL3 SL3 Third Level 1</a></li> </ul> </li> </ul> </li> <li><a href="#">First Level 4</a> </li> </ul>'
             ).insertAfter($(this)).menu().focus().focusout(function() {
                // When out of menu remove this instance
                $(this).empty().remove();
                // Flag false again
                flag = false;
            });
            // Find which menu item is clicked
            $('#mylist a').click(function() {
                var route=$(this).parent().text();
                if($(this).next().length==0){
                    alert('no more levels');
                    alert(route);
                    $('#LabelMenu').text(route);
                }else{
                    alert(route);
                    $('#LabelMenu').text($(this).text());
                }
            });
        }
        // Change flag on click
        flag = true;
    });
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BerkerYuceer/gp6H5/

Comment: it's 95% of what I need! the original idea was for the result to appear in another label, you got that. But the most important thing, is users should be able to do another "menu choice". Could you help me with that? in the fiddle, once I click on a level of the menu, I can't go and chose another one, that would have to be changed. Anyway, let me know if you can give me a hand with that since it's your code, but the bounty is yours anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('element.selector').on('click', function(event) {    
      event.preventDefault();
      // your logic
});
```

Comment: thanks for the input Andrey. But I've spent the last 30 minutes trying to adapt your answer to my problem and I wasn't able to figure it out. Could you enlighten me a bit more? Thanks again.

Comment: Daniel, аs far as I'm concerned, you need unbind original event, and bind your own. First of all you need disable default event hadler (that is I've written in my post).
Then you need delete `onclick` event handler of your element and unbind needless jQuery handlers. JQuery event listeners you can find in `$('element.selector').data('events')`

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way you can assign IDs to the menu items at all the levels. If so, these IDs can be progressive. i.e. in the main menu ids can be 1,2,3,4,5,6. And if 3,4,5 extend further then the child menu can have entries like (3_1, 3_2, 3_3), (4_1, 4_2) and so on.

This way when you finally select an element, you can use the ID to get the full qualified path of from where you traversed to this option.

This will only work out if somehow you can push ids to all the li elements.

Answer (score 0):

can make change in your plugin file there is function this.chooseItem their you can write your stuff

```
      this.chooseItem = function(item){
    menu.kill();

    //your custom code should go here:

    $('#menuSelection').text($(item).text());   
    location.href = $(item).attr('href');
};
```